# if struct exists in base workspace, save it

Tags: matlab, struct

I'm trying to save a struct, called 'Sum' from the Matlab workspace. The struct(1x1) is created inside a function.
I've written a small script:

```
    SumCheck = exist('Sum')
    if SumCheck == 1;
        save('SummaryTest','Sum')
    end
```

This works is i run it in the workspace - the file 'SummaryTest' is created in the working directory.
When I try running this in my GUI script the struct 'Sum' appears in the workspace but the test file is never saved out and i get no error message....
Does anyone have any ideas on how i can save out this struct as a file?
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: use `exist` with a specific type: `exist( 'Sum', 'var' )` to check for a variable and skip all sorts of tests for existing files/functions/directories etc.

Comment: @ Shai Thanks Shai, I have no problem getting this working for variables, only this d$^%^d struct! Thanks for the input though!

Comment: What do you mean by that? A struct is just a variable like a matrix or a cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in the GUI, the code probably checks for `Sum` in the GUI callback function workspace, not the base workspace. As it can't find it (`Sum` being in the base workspace), `SumCheck` is `false` and so the `save` command doesn't get executed.

Comment: Thanks! I fear that this might actually be the correct answer to my question! I guess it may just be an issue of where i'm placing the few lines of my save script. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to use evalin()

the callback that your GUI is executing doesn't have a variable in it's scope but it sounds like you have either explicitly created the SummaryTest structure in the base workspace, or maybe manually created it outside of the GUI.

evalin() allows you to specify where the "eval" is executed... for example you could

```
evalin('base', 'save(''SummaryTest'', ''Sum''')
```

my syntax is a bit rusty so take a look at evalin's documentation. note 'base' refers to the base workspace

HTH

Comment: Thanks janh, the struct is actaully sent to the workspace using: Sum = evalin('base','Sum'); The struct exists as soon as i load a file into my GUI and can be saved out using the script i wrote in the question. The problem is this only seems to work when i type that script into the workspace, not when i add it to the GUI function script.....Thanks for the advice though, your syntax is nicer than mine i think, i'll look into it and see if i can get it working.